# My Borderlands 2 DLC isn't detected?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm playing Borderlands 2 and I just downloaded a DLC called the Pirate's Booty for ten bucks, because I do not have a pass. It says that it is downloaded, but I cannot play it or access oasis. It says it is not downloaded, so I'm a bit confused about this.

How can I fix it and get the DLC in my game?

Answer (score 1):

I just redownloaded it and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Remember to mark your own answer as accepted after the 48 hour timer.